# Quarto: unnumbering Preface in TOC; output both PDF and html

Tags: rstudio, pandoc, quarto

I have put together a Quarto book by collecting a few articles I wrote previously. I didn't use the Quarto book template. Instead, I wrote a simple yaml for the book. The book compiled fine to html. Three questions:

1. The Preface in the sidebar is numbered (picture below). It is not supposed to. The first chapter should be "Atlas".

[image]

I have tried "`# Preface {.unnumbered}`" in the Preface. It didn't stop the numbering in the sidebar.

2. In RStudio, I have only one output option: html. What should I put in the yaml to have the pdf option? Here's the _quarto.yaml of the book:

```
project:
  type: book
  output-dir: _book

book:
  title: "The World"
  reader-mode: true

  chapters:
    - index.qmd  ## this is the Preface
    - Chap1.qmd  ## Chapter 1: Atlas
    - Chap2.qmd  ## Chapter 2: Titan
    - Chap3.qmd  ## Chapter 3: Goliath
    - Chap4.qmd  ## Chapter 4: Am Fear Liath Mòr

format:
  html:
    theme:
      - darkly
```

3. In the book, all the references to chapters/sections/pictures are underscored hyperlinks.  How to remove those underscores? Including "`code-link: false`" in the format section didn't seem working.

Comment: To get the pdf output, put `pdf: default` under the `format` yaml key in `_quarto.yaml` file.

Comment: Didn't work. I had tried this. I suspected other arguments are needed.

Comment: Preface is unnumbered by default now

Answer (score 0):

I figured out question #2. To turn on the PDF build option, add:

`output: pdf_document`

in _quarto.yml.